# How do I update certain columns within an entity in a Room database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database, android-architecture-components

Instead of passing in a new entity object as an arg into the DAO interface function for updating a row of data when referencing it by its primary key, is there a way to update **only a certain number of columns of an entity as opposed to all columns**? I tried updating only a few columns of my entity, but to no avail as follows:

```
@Query("UPDATE media SET name = :name AND description = :description" +
        " AND uri = :uri AND text = :text AND media_type = :mediaType" +
        " WHERE id = :id")
fun update(id: Int, name: String, description: String, uri: String, text: String, mediaType: String)
```

... apparently the "AND" keyword doesn't work as in only the first param, "name", got updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
"UPDATE media SET name = :name, description = :description," +
        " uri = :uri, text = :text, media_type = :mediaType" +
        " WHERE id = :id"
```

See [the SQLite documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) for more about `UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: I have a similar use case with UPDATE and SET that I call with an AsyncTask() since Room requires a background thread for CRUD.  Can you advise on the correct way to set up the call in the repository:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340870/android-how-to-update-single-room-column-with-dao-call-from-repository