# Android: update single Room column with Dao call from repository?

Tags: android-asynctask, repository, android-room, dao, android-viewmodel

I have a Room database and RecyclerView that shows a list of CardViews.  One of the database columns holds Sort Index values so the CardViews can easily be sorted and moved within the RecyclerView list.  I have a Dao call to update the Sort Index values whenever a CardView is moved, deleted or added.

Room requires CRUD on a background thread and the syntax I have in the AsyncTask() in the respository that calls the Dao method is wrong.    I am trying to pass the individual "int" sortOrders and the "int" sortIds.  What am I missing here?  Or would " Executor mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();" be a better solution here?

```
MainActivity
int sortId = -1;
int sortOrder = -1;
...
mViewModel.updateSortOrder(sortOrder, sortId);


ViewModel
...
public void updateSortOrder(int sortOrder, int sortId) {
   repository.updateSortOrder(sortOrder, sortId);
}


Repository
...
 public void updateSortOrder(int sortOrder, int sortId) {
    new UpdateSortOrderColAsyncTask(quickcardDao).execute(sortOrder, sortId);
}  

**I think this is where the syntax is not correct** 
private static class UpdateSortOrderColAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    private QuickcardDao asyncTaskDao;

    UpdateSortOrderColAsyncTask(QuickcardDao dao) {
        asyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Integer... params) {

        asyncTaskDao.updateSortorder(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}


Dao
@Query("UPDATE cards SET cardSortorder = :sortOrder WHERE cardId = :sortId")
void updateSortorder(int sortOrder, int sortId);
```

Comment: "I think this is where the syntax is not correct" -- what is the specific problem? If there is a syntax problem, you should be getting a specific syntax error. " Or would " Executor mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();" be a better solution here?" -- probably, since you do not need to do any work on the main application thread afterwards. Other alternatives would include RxJava and -- when you move to Kotlin -- coroutines.

Comment: @CommonsWare The Studio error is on the "(parms[0])".  It says "updateSortorder(int, int) in Dao cannot be applied to (Integer)"

Comment: `asyncTaskDao.updateSortorder(params[0])` needs to pass two parameters, not one.

Comment: yes, but not sure how to do properly.  Add an int sortOrder and an int sortId within the static class and then use  "asyncTaskDao.updateSortorder(params[sortOrder],sortId);"?

Comment: `asyncTaskDao.updateSortorder(params[0], params[1])`, based on how you are calling `execute()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Ah, now I understand.  You are a gentleman and a scholar.